# Broadcom BCM4352 driver not installed and wfi is not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom

I have Lenovo brand computer. I am a new user in Ubuntu world and have serious problem regarding wifi connection. After installation of Ubuntu, I tried to connect modem via wi-fi but could not do that. As I seen, the problem is related to installation of driver (Broadcom BCM4352). What should I do to solve this problem?

```
lspci
```

the output is here:

```
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the driver for your wireless card.

- open a terminal window from the Unity dashboard
- type `sudo apt-get update`
- type `sudo apt-get install dkms`
- type `sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms`
- turn off `Secure Boot` in your BIOS

Now your wireless should work.